# GLS estimator - derivation

Tags: econometrics, estimators, generalized-least-squares, blue

I'm stuck with the following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G790V.png):

> Given the model $$Y_t=\alpha+\beta X_t+u_t\,,$$ where the standard assumptions hold but $Eu_t^2=\sigma^2 X_t^2$, derive the GLS estimator.

Basically, all Gauss Markov assumptions hold, except for the Var of u, which is $\sigma^2 X^2$, rather than $\sigma^2  I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Hi: One of the OLS assumptions is that the regressor and the error term are uncorrelared. In your model,  the regressor and the error term are correlated so you need to make a transformation that will eliminate that correlation. See Aitken's estimator in an econometrics textbook or google for it. Another helpful google would be "GLS with known covariance matrix".

Comment: Please use MathJax for typesetting and add the 'self-study' tag (read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)) if this is some sort of homework.

Comment: @mlofton It's hard to discern such correlation in this formulation.  Indeed, it doesn't even seem to make sense, because "correlated" would imply $X_t$ is a random variable, but then the notation would *have* to use conditional expectations.  Wouldn't it be more accurate to characterize this as "uncorrelated but heteroscedastic"?

Comment: @whuber: You're right . It's heteroscedastic. Not correlated. My mistake. But I think you still need a transformation to transform it to a classical OLS so that it can be estimated. So, since the variance is proportional to the squared value of the regressor, I think you need WLS. where the diagional elements are inversely proportional so $\frac{1}{X^2}$. Thanks and apologies for the mistake.

Comment: and correct me again, if above is wrong. you never know :).

Comment: Actually, as @whuber said, the errors are uncorrelated but not constant among different observations (heteroskedastic). You know what, I tried to take the variance of the OLS estimator and the outcome seems to be σ2∗IdentityMatrix. Since the expected value of the OLS estimator is still beta, what should I say about the OLS? Is it still BLUE? If so, I guess I'm done